# Firebase Functions: Is there a way to iterate over multiple collections asynchronously?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When writing an API, I wanted to gather a collection of objects and pull each of their attributes. One attribute is a collection within each object. However, it doesn't seem like `<QuerySnapshot>` has any support for asynchronous iterating.

Pseudo-code (using TypeScript):

```
let objects = [];
const objectSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('object').get();

objectSnapshot.forEach(async (objectDoc) => {
    let values = [];
    const valueSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('object').doc(objectDoc.id).collection('value').get();

    valueSnapshot.forEach((valueDoc) => {
        values.push(valueDoc.data());
    });

    objects.push(values);
});

return objects;
```

The following code does not wait for `objects` to be populated and returns nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that forEach itself doesn't run synchronously, so you are returning the objects before they have a chance to be populated.

You have a few options to solve that, in your case I would recommend returning an array of promises and waiting for them to finish before returning. Something like this:

```
const objectSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('object').get();

// Creates an array of promises that can be awaited later
// You can use the docs property which is an array, and then you can use map on it
const promises = objectSnapshot.docs.map(async (objectDoc) => {
    // This will execute in parallel but will create a promise and add it to promises
    const valueSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('object').doc(objectDoc.id).collection('value').get();
    return valueSnapshot.docs.map((valueDoc) => valueDoc.data());
});

// Wait for all promises created before returning
return await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: This was a really and simple example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you're making here is that the callback you're passing to forEach should not be marked async.  All async functions immediately return a promise that resolves when all the other awaited async work in the function is complete.  This means that forEach is going to rapidly churn through all these promises *without waiting for them to resolve*.  After the iteration is complete, the async work inside each callback will complete.  This is not really how you want to use forEach.

If you want to do some async work for each document snapshot, and collect the results of all that async work, you should instead iterate the array of documents in `objectSnapshot.docs`.  Then, you can perform a further async work for each document.  Idiomatically for JavaScript, use the array's `map()` function to convert the array of document snapshots into an array of promises.  You can then use `Promise.all()` on that array of promises to wait for all the work to complete.